# SELECT DISTINCT from multiple row and DO NOT RETURN if containing row with undesired value

Tags: mysql

```
ID_Number|Subject_Code|Grade
000001   |Math        |Dropped
000001   |English     |Passed
000001   |Physics     |Passed
000002   |Math        |Passed
000002   |English     |Passed
000002   |Physics     |Passed
000003   |Math        |Passed
000003   |English     |Passed
000003   |Physics     |Passed
```

Now I want to `SELECT DISTINCT ID_Number` wherein all of the subject_code should have grade as Passed, the query should return 000002 and 000003 only since 000001 has 1 Dropped subject, other grade not to include is 'Withdrawn' and 'Failed'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_Number
FROM   <table>
WHERE  ID_Number not in(select ID_Number from <table> where Grade <> 'Passed')
```

#### [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efa94/1)

Comment: @paynet: Do you have an index on column ID_Number ?, if not better to have one